# what is the best way to make custom progressBar in javafx?

Tags: javafx, progress

in java swing or javafx.

if i want to make custom Progress Bar,

what is the best way to do it?

i can't find answer myself almost three month...

javafx css , javafx transition , swing lookandfeel.. etc..

what is the base principle. what is the best way?

please give me some way..

[(samples that want to make)](http://blog.platinastudio.com/60-attractive-and-best-examples-of-progress-status-bars-designs-to-be-used-in-websites/)

Comment: Just to give you a head start, this is a progress bar designed by Jewelsea - https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/6395481

Comment: Thanks ItachiUchiha.. but.. i can make this one. i want to make progress bar based custom image.. or animated one..